# Multiple text-based criteria with SUMPRODUCT

Tags: excel-formula

I'm struggling with a particular formula and despite much searching, I haven't been able to find a solution. I have the below sheet with my data (the sheet is named data):

|  | D | E | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Platinum | 8/11/2023 | Yellow |
| 2 | Gold | 8/11/2023 | Orange |
| 3 | Platinum | 8/11/2023 | White |

And I have two named arrays:

| Status | Color |
| --- | --- |
| Platinum | Yellow |
| Gold | Orange |

The formula I'm trying to use is:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(Data!$E:E=$A225),--(Data!$D:$D=Status),--(Data!$G:$G=Color))`

This formula appears on another sheet, and the reference A225 is the date 8/11/2023.

The expected result is 2, as I'm looking to count the number of records where column D has one of the values that appear on the 'status' named array, column G has one of the values that appear on the 'color' named array, and the date matches A225.

Instead, I'm getting an #N/A error. This is my first foray into using SUMPRODUCT, and I was able to make it work for all of the other calculations, for example: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(Data!$E:$E=$A225),--(ISNA(MATCH(Data!$G:$G,Color,0))))` works to show me the number of records where the date matches A225 and column G has a value that is not on the 'color' named array, and also `=SUMPRODUCT(--(Data!$E:$E=$A225),--(Data!$N:$N<>""))` works to show records where the date matches A225 and column N is blank.

Comment: Try e.g.  `=SUMPRODUCT((Data!E2:E4=A225)*ISNUMBER(MATCH(Data!D2:D4,Status,0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH(Data!G2:G4,Color,0)))`